# Application-defined or object-defined error with Format function

Tags: excel, vba

My cell is locked and I am filling the cell with data on Worksheet_Change event of a drop-down: `Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy").`

I am getting following error ::
*Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error*

I do not want to unlock the field as it is to be non-editable.

I also do understand that it is giving the error just because the cell is locked and it needs to perform the operation: `Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy").`.

What options do I have to make it working without unlocking the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlock the sheet, then make changes as needed, then lock again.

```
Me.Unprotect "pwd"
Me.Range("A1").Value = Format(Date,"mm-dd-yyyy")
Me.Protect "pwd"
```

Comment: I am not using a password to protect .... I am just using the following:ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(S, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(S + 9, lColumn)).Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect .. Please do let me know how to do using this approach..

Comment: @sid - Just take the password out and pass `""`. Otherwise, I am confused. You can just set the format (or cell value) in between protection and unprotection. Because locking a cell is meaningless when worksheet is unprotected state.

Comment: This is not working ... I am setting the ActiveSheet.Range().locked = False and then setting the value and then setting ActiveSheet.Range().Locked = True ... This is how the code looks like                ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(rps + 3, cps)).Locked = False
Cells(rps + 3, cps).Value = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(rps + 3, cps)).Locked = True

Comment: What I also found out is that when I click on the drop-down and select and option 2 things are happening: 1) A String in a cell is populated and 2) A date in a cell is populated ... Both the cells are locked .. .while it is able to write String to a locked cell BUT its giving"Application-defined OR Object-defined" Error while entering date. ??? What could be the reason...... Why excel vba is able to enter string in a locked cell but unable to enter date in a locked cell ?? Please help